# Error: <apex:column> must be the direct child of either <apex:dataTable> or <apex:pageBlockTable>

Tags: inputcheckboxes

i want to show checkbox before every contact in data table

```
<apex:page controller="ContactCheckEditController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Contact" tabStyle="contact">
               <apex:column headerValue="Edit">
                   <apex:inputCheckbox/>
               </apex:column>
               <apex:column value="{!cont.firstname}" headerValue="First Name"/>
               <apex:column value="{!cont.lastname}" headerValue="Last Name"/>
               <apex:column value="{!cont.phone}" headerValue="phone"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: you need wrapper class here example https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class

Comment: @Vipin The error message says it all. <apex:column> can only be used inside a <apex:pageBlockTable> or <apex:dataTable>. But in your code, you have used it directly inside <apex:pageBlock>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `<apex:column>` directly in `<apex:pageBlock>` .
You are code should be like this.

```
<apex:pageblock>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contactlist}" var="cont"><!--HERE I HAVE USED CONTACT AS LIST WHICH WILL BE IN CONTROLLER-->
       <apex:column headerValue="Edit">
                   <apex:inputCheckbox/>
               </apex:column>
               <apex:column value="{!cont.firstname}" headerValue="First Name"/>
               <apex:column value="{!cont.lastname}" headerValue="Last Name"/>
               <apex:column value="{!cont.phone}" headerValue="phone"/>

</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageblock>
```